# Cannot get JSON of HTTP Response

Tags: java

I'm simply trying to get the JSON returned by a HTTP GET request in Java 8. My code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

Response response = client.target("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
        .request()
        .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get();

String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

I get error with the last line:

```
java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to org.apache.http.HttpEntity
```

How can I simply get JSON from the response?

I have tried:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = client.target("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
            .request()
            .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(JSONObject.class);

    System.out.println("jsonObject is " + jsonObject);
```

I get the error:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class org.json.JSONObject, genericType=class org.json.JSONObject.
```

I also tried:

```
    Response response = client.target("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
            .request()
            .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get();

    System.out.println(response.getEntity().toString());
```

I get:
    org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$2@350d3f4d

How can something this basic - get me JSON from Response - be so difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May try to use `response.readEntity(String.class)` or `response.readEntity(HttpEntity.class)`. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class- 
That should give you a type you can work with.

EDIT:
`response.readEntity(String.class)` did work in the end.

Comment: Yes, i just get org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$2@350d3f4d

Comment: Actually response.readEntity(String.class) worked. Finally! Thanks

Comment: mh ok your JSON link is working so its not nullpointer there at least.

Comment: ah great :) You're welcome. Can you may accept this as the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

*The Problem is this part:*

```
// [...]
String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

---

**Try doing it like this:**

```
// [...]
String json_string = EntityUtils.toString((HttpEntity) response.getEntity());
```

It's just a guess though, since I don't have a running code i can not test it.

Comment: Yeah that probably works, still unchecked casts is dangerous, since getEntity() gives back null when the body is empty. 
I'd do HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); with a null check.

Comment: I get the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$2 cannot be cast to org.apache.http.HttpEntity

Comment: Ok then skip that case to HttpEntity and stick with HttpUrlConnector.
At least now you know that the object is an Instance of HttpUrlConnector.

Comment: @GammaG what do you mean? Why is getEntity() returning HttpUrlConnector?

Comment: Because of that cast exception. Your program is now trying to change the object what responce.getEntity() gives back to an instance of "HttpEntity" and fails. Because it cannot resolve the different types with each other. 
And your last exception looks like it's an instance of "org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector" what you get there.
HttpUrlConnector httpUrlConnector = (HttpUrlConnector) response.getEntity(); should work then.